# ktor handle all calls on a subdomain

Tags: ktor

I am trying to handle all calls (any path, any method) that happen on a subdomain.

I have configured a host route like:

```
host("mySubdomain.${application.environment.config.host}".toRegex()) {
        get(".*".toRegex()) { MyHandler.handle(call) }
        post(".*".toRegex()) { MyHandler.handle(call) }
        // ...
    }
```

There must be a better way than matching all nested routes by HTTP method, but I can't figure it out. I tried to replace this as:

```
host("mySubdomain.${application.environment.config.host}".toRegex()) {
        handle { MyHandler.handle(call) }
    }
```

But it does not handle any calls. What is the proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle all calls by using the tailcard path parameter:

```
route("{...}") {
    handle {
        call.respondText { "All calls" }
    }
}
```